# How do I map a One To Many Relationship with Composite Primary Key in JPA (Hibernate)?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

My tables look like this:

```
School
-------
school_id (pk)
...

Student
school_id (pk) (fk)
student_id (pk)
...
```

So using JPA (Hibernate), I tried something like this.

```
@Entity
@Table("SCHOOL")
public School {
    @Column(name = "SCHOOL_ID")
    private String schoolId;
    
    @OneToMany
    private List<Student> students;
}

@Entity
@Table("STUDENT")
public Student {
    @EmbeddedId
    private StudentPK studentPK;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SCHOOL_ID")
    private School school; 
}

@Embeddable
public StudentPK implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "SCHOOL_ID")
    private String schoolId;

    @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID"
    private String studentId;
}
```

When I do this, I frequently get an error that says that the foreign key constraint is being violated on runtime. I suspect that JPA is trying to generate a new foreign key called "SCHOOL_ID" instead of using the existing column from my composite key, but I'm not sure how to force it to use the existing column.

Comment: Where is the @Id annotation on the School entity? Also, could you post the error stacktrace? In which operation the error happens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These relationships should be mapped a bit differently:

```
@Entity
@Table("SCHOOL")
public School {
    @Column(name = "SCHOOL_ID")
    private String schoolId;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="school")
    private List<Student> students;
}

@Entity
@Table("STUDENT")
public Student {
    @EmbeddedId
    private StudentPK studentPK;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("schoolId")
    private School school; 
}

@Embeddable
public StudentPK implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "SCHOOL_ID")
    private String schoolId;

    @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID"
    private String studentId;
}
```

Note the `@OneToMany.mappedBy` attribute on `School.students` and `@MapsId` annotation on `Student.school`.

Derived identities are discussed (with examples) in the [JPA 2.2 spec](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf) in section 2.4.1.

Comment: This comment got me most of the way there. It turns out that I had stumbled across this solution before, but it still didn't work because the h2 Embedded Database was automatically generating a database schema with an integer instead of a string.